# Update jsrsasign from 0.0.3 to 10.8.6

Tags: npm, package.json, package-lock.json, jwk, npm-vulnerabilities

I need assistance in he procedure to update jsrsasign npm library under jws-jwk tree.

It's currently giving me the following tree when using `npm ls jsrsasign`.

```
jws-jwk@0.1.4
  └── jsrsasign@0.0.3
```

I tried npm install jsrsasign@10.8.6 but its adding jsrsasign as separate library in package.json. Can anyone guide on updating the library under jws-jwk.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. You might want to share _why_ you think you need to upgrade.